Solana Wallet address automatically generated
I'm building a betting platform on Solana, with a platform token. When a user registers on our platform and enters their email address, they can log in and navigate to the wallet section. There, they will automatically see a Solana wallet address generated for them. Users can then deposit Solana or our platform token, which is on the Solana network. I'm looking for a way to implement this without using WalletConnect.

If you are looking for alternatives to embedded wallet, here are a few providers I can suggest.

Dynamic
Portal

Phantom also teased one a while back and I can guess that they might release it during breakpoint.
